# Multiple layer data in one delimited text layer

Tags: qgis, raster, layers, mysql

I am a GIS beginner.

I'm exporting several point coords from a Mysql database, and importing into QGIS using delimited text layer.

I need to plot all the points and set the symbology to distinguish them accordly

This is my dataset:

[image: data set]

The thing is, that each point has two values to plot (amount and growth) and they have to be grouped by category (in this case weed).

One approach that i was taking was create rule based symbology, eg: one per weed type and amount value. But i think this is not viable, because i have multiple combinations.

Other approach, was to split the dataset. One per weed type. But also not viable.

Is there a better way?

Can QGIS take one delimited text layer and split and import several layers based on some param?

I've tried the Split vector layer tool, but no auto import. Only split.

Maybe with some virtual layers?

Comment: you're already using MYSQL - could you create views on the database side and simply have QGIS consume the views? You have complete control over the data at that point, which is a preferable place to be